# Java millis time with hourly resolution

Tags: java, time, timezone, utc, localtime

How do I get java time millis in UTC ignoring the minutes and seconds.

For instance :
If it is October 10 2019, 1:10:59 AM , it should get the `Time` or millis for
October 10 2019, 1 AM.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Please see [ask], you are required to show some effort before you ask a question on SO, thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to 1. parse the input, 2. format the output. Just use a format pattern that excludes minutes and seconds, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary:

```
Instant
.now()
.truncatedTo( 
    ChronoUnit.HOURS 
)
.toEpochMilli()
```

> 1570600800000

---

java.time, the modern Java date and time API has got exactly the method you need: many of the classes have a `truncatedTo` method for needs like yours.

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Rough milliseconds:                        " + now.toEpochMilli());
    Instant currentWholeHour = now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    System.out.println("Milliseconds ignoring minutes and seconds: "
            + currentWholeHour.toEpochMilli());
```

When running this snippet just now the output was:

> ```
> Rough milliseconds:                        1570604053787
> Milliseconds ignoring minutes and seconds: 1570600800000
> ```

I know very well that the first line is what you asked *not* to have. I only included it for you to see the difference.

The truncation happens in UTC. If you are in a time zone whose offset is not a whole number of hours from UTC, the results may not be as you had expected. Examples of such time zones include Asia/Kathmandu, America/St_Johns some of the year also Australia/Lord_Howe.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LocalDate#atTime`:

```
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalDateTime.now().getHour(), 0, 0);
```

This will give you current date with hour and minutes and seconds set to 0.

And to get milliseconds in UTC:

```
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalDateTime.now().getHour(), 0, 0).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
```

Jon Skeet notices, that calling `now` might give unexpected results in corner cases. To be sure, we can call it once and then convert it to `LocalDate` with mentioned solution:

```
var currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
var currentDate = currentTime.toLocalDate();
```

Or the other way around - get `LocalDate` first and use `LocalDate#atStartOfDay`.

Comment: He wants to completelty exclude it from the output string though. I would recommend just using a formatter with a format pattern that does not include minutes and seconds at all.

Comment: I want a `Time` object or millis. But it should be UTC

Comment: @Zabuza i agree, but I can't see explicitly, that this should be converted to string

Comment: Using `now()` twice like this is always dangerous, because if the clock rolls over from 23:59:00 to 00:00:00 you could return a result which is out by nearly 24 hours.

Comment: @NoviceUser: What do you mean by a `Time` object? There's no `Time` class in the Java standard library as far as I'm aware. Do you mean `LocalTime`? `LocalDateTime`? This is where it would be helpful if you could show what you've already tried - it'll make it much clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant getting millis so sorry for confusion

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for noticing the corner case, edited the answer

Comment: when doing `currentTime.toLocalDate()` how will that ensure to use UTC?

Comment: @NoviceUser it is, when your application is in UTC, otherwise you would have to convert it first

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're interested in UTC milliseconds, and there are a whole number of milliseconds per hour, you can do this with simple arithmetic. For most calendrical computations I really wouldn't recommend that, but in this case I think it's the simplest approach. Something like this:

```
private static final long MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1);

// Injecting a clock makes the method testable. You can use Clock.systemUTC()
// for the system clock.
public static long truncateMillisToHour(Clock clock) {
    long millisSinceEpoch = clock.millis();
    // Truncate to the nearest hour
    long hoursSinceEpoch = millisSinceEpoch / MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
    // Then multiply up again
    return hoursSinceEpoch * MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
}
```

Note that if the clock is for *before* the epoch, this will round *up* to the nearest hour, but if you're taking the genuine "current time" then that's unlikely to be a problem.

(I wrote this answer before seeing Ole V.V.'s answer with `truncatedTo`, which is a very nice approach.)